# How to make a consult with a variable?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vuejs2, controller

Im in vue and im trying to make a consult where depending on the variable Provider_id, it should show only certain data that is correlated with the id in question, i have already tried it and it does work but i have to input the provider_id manually in the url, is there any way to insert a variable or to make the comparasion?
I have already tried adding a "+$id" in the url but it doesnt work
(im learning english so forgive any grammar errors)

```
ConsultPurchasesProv() {
this.axios
        .get("/api/TSO-consult-purchases-of-prov?provider_id="), {
          params: {
            selection_id: selection_id,
            type: type,
            provider_id: provider_id,
            nameprov: this.searchC.id,
            brand_id: brand_id,
            user_id: user_id,
            purchase_id: purchase_id,
            date: this.date,
            date2: this.date2,
            type: self.status,
            invoice: self.invoice,
          },
          
        })
        .then(function (response) {
          if (response.data.status == "200") {
            self.purchasesItems = response.data.purchaseorders;
            self.totalExpensesMonth = _.sumBy(
              self.purchasesItems,
              function (o) {
                return o.total;
              }
            );
            self.month = response.data.month;
            self.year = response.data.year;
          }
        });
}
```

Comment: Since provider_id is part of your params, try removing it from the url (just `"/api/TSO-consult-purchases-of-prov"`. You could also try adding it to the url with `"/api/TSO-consult-purchases-of-prov?provider_id=" + provider_id`

Comment: it detected it as Null and it didnt work any other idea?